# When mocking a module with Jest, is there any difference between mocking it using the fully-qualified name (FQN) vs destructuring the module?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

Let's assume I'm using `writeFile` and `readFile` as follows:

```
// index.js
import { writeFile, readFile } from 'fs/promises';

// code using writeFile and readFile
```

If I want to mock them, is there a practical difference between the following?

1. Using the fully-qualified name (FQN), e.g., `fs/promises`.

```js
jest.mock('fs/promises', () => ({
  writeFile: jest.fn(),
  readFile: jest.fn(),
}));
```

2. Destructuring the module, e.g., `fs`, which returns `promises`.

```js
jest.mock('fs', () => ({
  promises: {
    writeFile: jest.fn(),
    readFile: jest.fn(),
  }
}));
```

**Note:** I don't know if fully-qualified name and module destructuring is the right terminology but hopefully the examples convey what I mean well enough.